# Google chrome connects multiple times to java HttpServer

Tags: java, httpserver

I have this tiny java http server:

```
public class HttpServer {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int port;
        ServerSocket server_socket;
        try {
            port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            port = 8080;
        }
        try {
            server_socket = new ServerSocket(port, 0, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"));
            System.out.println("httpServer running on port "
                    + server_socket.getLocalPort()
                    + " address " + server_socket.getInetAddress()
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

When I connect with google chrome to localhost IDE console writes following:

```
httpServer running on port 8080 address localhost/127.0.0.1
New connection accepted /127.0.0.1:54839
New connection accepted /127.0.0.1:54840
```

Seems like google chrome connects two times to the server, but changing its port. 
Why is it can be?

Comment: You have something else going on in the browser page.  Chrome is only going to connect on the port in your URL, presumably port 8080.  These other connections are being spun off by something else.  An extention, JavaScript logic, etc.

Comment: 127.0.0.1:54839 and 127.0.0.1:54840 are where the requests are coming from, not where they are being received, 127.0.0.1:8080.  I have seen the same thing happening running a node server and hitting it with Chrome or IE.

Answer (score 0):

Since port 8080 on your client is already taken, the client's operating system will map the connection to a different unused port on the client. Your client connects from port 54839 and 54840 to port 80 on the server. To allow another client to connect to your server, the port is automatically redirected to an untaken port.

Here's a list of what happens...

1. Client opens up a Socket to connect to your server
2. Client's OS checks if the port the Socket is trying to connect to is used and if not looks for an unused port.
3. Client's OS assigns the socket to the unused local port it's detected in step 2.
4. Server receives connection request and accepts it. Server's OS redirects the connection from port 8080 to another port to allow more clients to connection.
5. Client and server have a chat and then disconnect.

54839 and 54840 are ports the OS assigned to the two Sockets your browser created when attempting to connect to your local website.

---

Edit: To correctly answer your question, the resources you send the browser causes it to connect twice. Once to retrieve the first resource and a second time to retrieve the resource the first requires.